# Google maps suggestions. filter suggestions based on first input

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm busy with google maps. All is working fine.
Got a map on the frontpage that draws a route, that comes from 2 user inputs.

Now i want to filter the suggestions from the second input, based on the location of the first input.

At the moment if in the first input a address in the netherlands is entered, suggestions start giving locations in USA, if you dont specify a full addres.

Is it possible to give a radius or something to the second input before google sends suggestions back?
All i found has a limit of 50KM, while most rides are more then 50KM.

Based on country isn't gonna work, as it is international.

Comment: so you like to restrict the results in the 2nd input to the country of the selection  in the first input?

Comment: Not the country, more like a radius. its a international site. So if a customer travel from the Netherlands to Belgium for example, i want the results from netherlands and belgium. Right now the results starts in the USA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`radius` is not a possible option, but you may define an area(`LatLngBounds`) around the place where the results should be **preferred** via the `bounds`-option of an `Autocomplete`.(a **restriction** is only possible for countries)

Such an area ma be calculated via [`google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en&csw=1#spherical)

Example:

```js
      function init() {

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
            zoom: 1,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
            noClear: true,
            disableDefaultUI: true
          }),
          diagonal = 250, //length of the diagonal in km
          inputs = map.getDiv().querySelectorAll('input[id^="pac"]'),
          acs = [],
          area = new google.maps.Rectangle(),
          marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
          });

        for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length, i < 2; ++i) {
          map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(inputs[i]);
          acs.push(new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(inputs[i]));
          if (i === 1) {
            //first input
            google.maps.event.addListener(acs[0], 'place_changed', function() {
              //when there is a valid place
              if (this.getPlace().geometry) {

                var center = this.getPlace().geometry.location,
                  bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(center);
                //create a area around the  place
                bounds.extend(google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(center, diagonal / 2 * 1000, 135));
                bounds.extend(google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(center, diagonal / 2 * 1000, 315));

                //just a rectangle to visualize the used area
                area.setOptions({
                  map: map,
                  bounds: bounds
                });

                map.fitBounds(bounds);
                //set the prefered search-area for the 2nd autocomplete
                acs[1].setBounds(bounds);
              } else {
                acs[1].setBounds(null);
                area.setMap(null);
              }
            });
            //2nd input
            google.maps.event.addListener(acs[1], 'place_changed', function() {
              //when there is a valid place
              if (this.getPlace().geometry) {
                //draw a marker and set the center of the map
                var center = this.getPlace().geometry.location;
                map.setCenter(center)
                marker.setOptions({
                  map: map,
                  position: center
                })
              } else {
                marker.setMap(null);
              }
            });
          }
        }
      }
```

```css
 html,
 body,
 #map_canvas {
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
 }
```

```html
<div id="map_canvas">
  <input id="pac1">
  <input id="pac2">
</div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&libraries=places,geometry&callback=init"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that does exactly what i want! Accepted as answer!